# Unable to control the width of UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, uitextview

I am making an application where I need to create a UITextView on the screen. The height and width of the TextView should go on increasing as the user types i.e. the height and width of the TextView should change according to its content.

However I have been able to control the height of the TextView through the **myTextView.ContentSize.height**. But I could not find a way to control the width of the TextView according to its content.

Even **myTextView.contentSize.width** doesn't work for me.

I am doing all my frame calculations within **textViewDidchange** delegate method of UITextView.

Any suggestions??

Comment: is the content size smaller than the size of the `UITextView`?

Answer (score 1):

In the `textViewDidChange`,

```
CGSize constraintSize; 
CGSize labelSize; 

constraintSize = CGSizeMake(myTextView.frame.size.width, 480); 

NSString    *text   =   myTextView.text;
text                =   [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
text                =   [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if([text stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding])
{
    text            =   [text stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

// Note that in the below line you must use the font as exact as you use for textview

labelSize           =   [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 16] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

In the `labelSize` you can find the expected size of the text view.
You can set the frame of `myTextView` as

```
myTextView.frame    =   CGRectMake(myTextView.frame.origin.x,myTextView.frame.origin.y,labelSize.width,labelSize.height);
```

Think this will works for you. Try it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but my textview is growing by height only. Its not growing in width.